# Enable additional targets with system-provided rust packages, not rustup

Tags: rust, ubuntu-20.04, rustup

I wanted to put together a Rust toolchain using the system package manager rather than downloading the rustup installer, and cross-compile for a Raspberry Pi 3

To that end, in Ubuntu 20.04 I have installed `rustc` and `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

However, the `cargo build --bins --release --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` command fails with

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` target may not be installed
```

Is there a way to get this working, other than `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh && rustup target add arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`?

Comment: well create a package for this target in your package manager. Do you have any experience with linux ?!? this question is mostly off topic

Comment: @Stargateur I have a huge amount of experience with linux. I have no idea what "this target" is. Is it a package downloaded from somewhere? Some config change? Is it already available from Ubuntu repos but I didn't find the name?

Comment: well here https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/new-target.html have fun

Comment: In order to do cross development (in any language) you need to have the standard library for the target platform. For C on Debian this means installing e.g. `libc6-armhf-cross` and `libc6-dev-armhf-cross`. For Rust I don't see any appropriate packages, so you will need to either create the Ubuntu packages yourself or use `rustup`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are better off using a docker image to help.

I found this in general:

https://kerkour.com/rust-reproducible-cross-compilation-with-docker/

and, for armv7 I'd say something akin to:

```sh
apt update && apt upgrade -y
apt install -y g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-dev-armhf-cross

rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
rustup toolchain install stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

under Ubuntu should do the trick.

Comment: Can you clarify why this answer proposes using `rustup` when the post explicitly asks how to do this without `rustup`?

Comment: @kmdreko because by using that as a starting point the OP can still build their system package manager based tool-chain bundle; and if they ignore my rustup commands it still provides all of the correct dependencies information to the OP.